DataWeave - Add additional item after iteration used for list
I'm trying to create the following XML:
<ns10:Payload>
   <ns6:MeterReadings>
      <ns6:MeterReading>
         <ns6:Readings>
            <ns6:reportedDateTime>2024-06-02T23:15:11.09+02:00</ns6:reportedDateTime>
            <ns6:timeStamp>2024-06-02T23:14:39+02:00</ns6:timeStamp>
            <ns6:value>0.234</ns6:value>
            <ns6:ReadingType ref="0.0.0.6.0.1.54.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.128.3.29.0"/>
         </ns6:Readings>
         <ns6:Readings>
            <ns6:reportedDateTime>2024-06-02T23:15:11.09+02:00</ns6:reportedDateTime>
            <ns6:timeStamp>2024-06-02T23:14:39+02:00</ns6:timeStamp>
            <ns6:value>0.233</ns6:value>
            <ns6:ReadingType ref="0.0.0.6.0.1.54.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.64.3.29.0"/>
         </ns6:Readings>
         <ns6:UsagePoint>
            <ns6:mRID>ES00TRAFGISS03268T120F</ns6:mRID>
         </ns6:UsagePoint>
      </ns6:MeterReading>
   </ns6:MeterReadings>
</ns10:Payload>

I've used the ++ operation to add the element UsagePoint at the end of the list but Mule gives me an error due to me mixing an array with an object.
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadingsMessage
ns ns01 http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message
ns ns02 http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings

var meterReadings = payload.MeterReadings
var meterReading = meterReadings.MeterReading
var readings = meterReading.readings[0] as Array<T>

---
ns0#CreatedMeterReadings: {
    ns0#Header: {
        ns01#Verb: "reply",
        ns01#Noun: "MeterReadings"
    },
    ns0#Payload: {
        ns02#MeterReadings: {
            ns02#MeterReading: readings map ((reading) -> {
                ns02#Readings: {
                    ns02#reportedDateTime: reading.reportedDateTime,
                    ns02#timeStamp: reading.timeStamp,
                    ns02#value: reading.value,
                    ns02#ReadingType: reading.ReadingType
                } 
            })
            reduce ($$ ++ $) 
            ++ ns02#UsagePoint: {
                ns02#mRID: "example"
            }
        }
    }
}

Is it possible to do what I'm trying?

The script that you shared is incomplete. Please [edit] the question to add a complete script that can be used to reproduce the issue. Also include the input.

@aled added complete example, sorry!

When there are errors add the complete text to the question. Also a complete input to reproduce. Read how to write a [mre].

I could not reproduce the issue, probably because you haven't share enough for a full reproduction. However looking at the desired output, you can use the reduce() function to convert the inner array to an object. That will achieve the desired output.
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://something
ns ns02 http://somethingelse
---
ns0#CreatedMeterReadings: {
    ns0#Payload: {
        ns02#MeterReadings: {
            ns02#MeterReading: payload map ((reading) -> {
                    ns02#Readings: {
                        ns02#reportedDateTime: reading.reportedDateTime,
                        ns02#timeStamp: reading.timeStamp,
                        ns02#value: reading.value,
                        ns02#ReadingType: reading.ReadingType
                    } 
                }) 
                    reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ item)  
                    ++ ns02#UsagePoint: {
                        ns02#mRID: "example"
                    }
        }
    }
}

I used this dummy data as input an changed the expression for MeterReading accordingly:
[
    {
        "reportedDateTime": 123,
        "timeStamp": 1,
        "value": 111,
        "ReadingType": "x"
    },    
    {
        "reportedDateTime": 321,
        "timeStamp": 2,
        "value": 222,
        "ReadingType": "y"
    }
]

Output:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:CreatedMeterReadings xmlns:ns0="http://something">
  <ns0:Payload>
    <ns02:MeterReadings xmlns:ns02="http://somethingelse">
      <ns02:MeterReading>
        <ns02:Readings>
          <ns02:reportedDateTime>123</ns02:reportedDateTime>
          <ns02:timeStamp>1</ns02:timeStamp>
          <ns02:value>111</ns02:value>
          <ns02:ReadingType>x</ns02:ReadingType>
        </ns02:Readings>
        <ns02:Readings>
          <ns02:reportedDateTime>321</ns02:reportedDateTime>
          <ns02:timeStamp>2</ns02:timeStamp>
          <ns02:value>222</ns02:value>
          <ns02:ReadingType>y</ns02:ReadingType>
        </ns02:Readings>
        <ns02:UsagePoint>
          <ns02:mRID>example</ns02:mRID>
        </ns02:UsagePoint>
      </ns02:MeterReading>
    </ns02:MeterReadings>
  </ns0:Payload>
</ns0:CreatedMeterReadings>


Thank you so much for the help. I tried the solution, unfortunately a type error is shown: Unable to call: reduce with arguments: (Array<{|ns0#Readings...2011/MeterReadings  , ($, $$) -> ?). Reasons: - Repeated field: Readings is not supported by: `{|ns0#Readings: {|ns...2011/MeterReadings |- From: reduce(items: Array, callback: (item: T, accumulator: T) -> T) -> T | Null

BWT, I'm generating the data from a Java component so that's why maybe types are more confusing

It is difficult to reproduce since you are not providing actual data however I believe it is related to the automatic initialization of the accumulator in reduce(), I updated my example with an explicit initialization to an empty object. Try this change and let me know.

Thank you so much! Found an alternative as well that works. Sorry for not being able to provide a complete example, some logic is being created using auto-generated classes and a custom Java component.

You can reduce the problem to avoid that dependency in the question. That's the idea of a [mre].

My solution was to use an object to define the hierarchy and use an array for the readings list:
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns met http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadingsMessage
ns mes http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message
ns met1 http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#

var meterReadings = payload.MeterReadings
var meterReading = meterReadings.MeterReading
var readings = meterReading.readings[0]

//var requestData = read(vars.queryOperation.RequestData, "application/json")

---
met#CreatedMeterReadings: {
    met#Header: {
        mes#Verb: "reply",
        mes#Noun: "MeterReadings"
    },
    met#Payload: {
        met1#MeterReadings: {
            met1#MeterReading: {
                met1#Readings: readings map ((reading) -> {
                    met1#reportedDateTime: reading.reportedDateTime,
                    met1#timeStamp: reading.timeStamp,
                    met1#value: reading.value,
                    met1#ReadingType @("ref": reading.ReadingType.ref): {}
                }),
                met1#UsagePoint: {
                    met1#mRID: "usagePoint"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

